# Since purchasing developer license iphone app can't write .plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

I recently paid the $99 for the dev license to be able to load my app on my iPhone. Prior to doing that my app was able to write a simple 'names.plist' file to the Documents directory of my app in the simulator. I was able to launch the app at a later time in the simulator and some text would be retained inside the file. Since purchasing the license and installing the app on my phone, the app does write to the sandbox Documents directory in the simulator or phone. It seems like the developer license changed something.

The code for when it worked has not changed and correctly returned the sandbox Documents directory. It is below. I've also included an NSLog print of what the app shows now for the directory and filename with the same code. It is for a file named 'Documentsname.plist', not the 'names.plist' I am wanting. I greatly appreciate any help! Thanks.

```
//.h
#define username @"name.plist"

// .m -- Define and return this App's sandbox iOS Documents Directory
- (NSString *)userFilePath {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:username];

}
```

An NSLog of the path that is trying to write to and then read from is below:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/AF36A4E1-5387-4B10-8F3A-A69AAA307FE4/Documentsname.plist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:username];
```

You are just appending a string, not a path. By appending a "path component", it automatically adds/removes needed/unneeded slashes.

I would also recommend not combining the username and ".plist".

```
#define username @"name"

return [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:username]stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help. Am I supposed to resolve this question now somehow?

Comment: @phil999: Marking as an answer, as you have done (with or without an upvote) will signify that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What about simply adding the missing "/"?

```
#define username @"/name.plist"
```